# Configure Postgres container logs to be sent to GCP Stackdriver

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm using GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine) on Google Cloud, and I have a Postgres container.

I want to configure Postgres to send its logs to Stackdriver in JSON format.

I did not find documentation for this, and I'm a newbie in Postgres. How can I do this?